# Xamarin - how to get ListView source data from two classes?

Tags: c#, listview, data-binding, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin `ListView` in a `Xamarin.Form` application. It is initialised as below:

```
ListView listView = new ListView
        {
            HasUnevenRows = true,
            ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(StudentCell)),
            ItemsSource = register.StudentList,
            SeparatorColor = Color.FromHex("#ddd")
        };
        listView.ItemSelected += OnSelection;
```

I can't seem to find anything online about how/ if I can make the `ItemsSource` two seperate classes. I have a student list that contains data such as Name and Status, but need to load an image from another class for each item in the student list.

Is there any way to do this?

Alternatively, I have made a custom cell type, `StudentCell`. Is there a way to specify a binding to another class (not a student) from within the custom template?

Comment: are you not able to add a property like StudentImage to the items the are returned from register.StudentList ?

Comment: @Pete I didn't think this was possible in C#. I have had a search and it seems an `ExpandoObject` can do this? I'll give that a try and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility to consider is that from the `register.StudentList`, lets say its of type `Student`, should you not be able to include a `StudentImage` property in that class, then perhaps derive a new class, say `StudentWithImage` that inherits from `Student` so it will have the same properties.

You can then add your `StudentImage` property to this new class that inherits from `Student`.

On the result set returned, you can then enumerate all the instances of it, and set the `StudentImage` property to the appropriate value by performing a lookup on your other class.

You can then just bind your list of `StudentWithImage`s to your `Xamarin.Forms` `List` and work from a single datasource.

Answer (score 2):

This is what the VM (ViewModel) in the MVVM pattern is for.  It allows your View (ListView) to display data from more than one model (Student and Image) by creating a ViewModel class that combines data from multiple sources.

In your case, you might create a StudentViewModel class that contains both a Student and an Image.  Then you would bind your ListView to the ViewModel class.